# Replay the game after losing or winning

Tags: java

I created a space shooter game and after it finishes I display a menu and the option to play again. When I press it it's starting from where I left (if the game was lost). I do not have a game loop and I think the problem is from disposing the enemies and the player after the game finishes.

```
private static ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
    //constructor
    public GameFrame(){
        setFocusable(true);
        addMouseListener(new MouseInput());
        mainTimer = new Timer(12,this);
        mainTimer.start();
        setupScene();
    private void setupScene()
    {
        player = new Player(300,520);
        enemyCount = 10;
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapt(player));
        startGame();
    }

    private void clearScene(){
        score=0;
        level=1;
        player = null;
        for(int j=0; j<enemies.size(); j++)
        {
            removeEnemy(enemies.get(j));
        }
    }

    public void startGame() {
        for (int i = 0; i < enemyCount; i++) {
            addEnemy(new Enemy(rand.nextInt(600), -rand.nextInt(600)));
        }
    }
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(State == STATE.GAME) {
            player.update();
            repaint();

            for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
                Enemy tempEnemy = enemies.get(i);
                tempEnemy.update();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < missiles.size(); i++) {
                Missile m = missiles.get(i);
                m.update();
                repaint();
            }
        }
        checkGameOver();
```

And here is the method where I change the game state if the game is lost

```
 private void checkGameOver() {
      for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
        if (enemies.get(i).getY() >= 570)
        {
            State = STATE.GAME_OVER;
            clearScene();
            setupScene();
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you just need to clear the `enemies` array, you can possibly use `enemies.clear();` Using a loop to remove from a `List` can be problematic.

Comment: thank you that worked, now i have the problem with the  player.If i play and an enemy falls down without killing him i lost, then if i press play botton the game starts and when i shoot it is shooting 2 missiles, the one from the current player and another one from the position where i died last time, but only the current player is drawed